# Server Side Swift Vapor - Model inheritance

Tags: swift, vapor, server-side-swift

Is it possible to subclass models and inherit the superclass's properties
so in the end I have the models:

class User 

- class Student : User

- class Teacher : User

With the intention of creating this: https://ryanbigg.com/2008/09/multiple-user-access-levels

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible cause model class should be `final`. Also inheritance isn't a good idea while you're working with codables, cause super's properties wouldn't be encoded without manual code. So just create these two models separately :)

Comment: I would personally create a `User` model with a `status` property. The type of the property could be a `Status` enum. I've done this before and it works wonderfully.

Comment: You could create a protocol. `protocol User : Codable { //properties }`

Answer (score 1):

After reading the Discord chat as of March 1, 2019 there is an open issue here for fluent: https://github.com/vapor/fluent-kit/issues/8.